# JDBC claims table does not exist

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

I am using the embedded h2 database inside of the play framework. I am trying to insert some test data into it, then retrieve that data.

[image: Issue]

as you can see, the right side shows me that there is indeed a suscribers table, but when being run, I get this:

[image: Error]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Dumb question, but what happens if you do 'insert into suscribers values (?,?)' instead of 'insert into SUSCRIBERS values (?,?)' ?

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the same database? With embedded DBs that auto-generate missing files and accept relative paths it is easy to mistake the disk location.

Comment: How is it a dumb question? it does the same thing when I use `suscribers`

Comment: @DavidJames dumb question as, "Hey this might sound dumb, but what happens if you use lower case" not "Your question is bad and you should feel bad, what happens when you use lower case?"

Comment: Your software are not connected with the same database as your IntelliJ IDE. Please provide your jdbc connection string.

Answer (score -1):

Try with `dbName.tblName`, for example:

```
insert into dbName.tblName ...
```

and also:

You are inserting 2 columns out of 3 columns per table. I think you have to mention column names as well.

Comment: the other column should is a `bigint auto_increment`, how do I mention it in JDBC?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, but you would do `INSERT INTO subscribers (name, email) VALUES (?,?)`